# Online browser game Architecture

Tags: architecture, browser

I want to develop an online browser game which is heavy in graphics and functionality.I am new to these technologies so pardon me for any vague questions:

1. How and where should i start?
2. What should be my front-end programming choices and workflow?
3. What should be my back-end programming choices and workflow?
4. Do i need a game engine for a browser game?

Comment: What do you mean with game engine?

Comment: When you say browser games, do you mean "flash" games or "pure HTML" games?

Comment: Pardon me again but what you will call a game like Farmville?

Answer (score 2):

**How and where should i start?**

I assume you already have vision of what the game should look like. Have some mind experiments and see where your vision leads. Be positive and do not let any doubts to creep into your mind. Try some prototyping, evaluate them and adjust your plans accordingly.

If you have no experience in technologies you are going to use, it is almost certain you will encounter some roadblocks, where those technologies do not allow you to achieve exactly what yo want. It happens to everyone. Learn from that experience and move on.

**What should be my front-end programming choices and workflow?**

*HTML5* solution will be most accessible, but it is arguably the most difficult to implement. You have to know Javascript very well.

*Flash* solution can have really cool graphic effects with little effort, but there are some people concerned about resource consumption of Flash.

*Silverlight* is Flash for Microsoft developers. It is the least accessible for the users.

**What should be my back-end programming choices and workflow?**

Some popular web frameworks: [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) (Ruby), [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) (PHP), [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) (.NET), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)(Python)

I'd suggest you always implement features in top-down manner: start with the UI (what user wants to see/be able to achieve) down to "business logic" down to DB.

With the rise of NOSQL Databases, they may be the right fit, instead of the traditional Relational Databases. When choosing DB, evaluate read/write ratio of your app. Usual recipes are for apps where reads are more frequent than writes. I suspect this may not be the case for games, so you should be careful by following them.

**Do i need a game engine for a browser game?**

I suppose you are talking about full-blown game development framework, where you are left with just filling in placeholders? I would't choose such thing, and even don't know of the choices. It would constrain my options too much. However, I'd certainly use some libraries like 3D Graphics Engine to offload nonessential functionality and focus on what makes my game unique.

But there is another thing you may call game engine - it is the core logic of your game. I'd suggest you pay attention and model this core behavior explicitly (most probably, in OOP style). Have it all in one place (rather than scattered around all over the codebase). Games tend to have quite complex logic compared to average apps, and if you do not model it properly, you may end up having hard time understanding it later.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an elaborated answer

Comment: just to add : GWT can generate Javascript from Java code. So you may not need to understand javascript if you understand Java.

Comment: They are talking javascript is gonna overtake the world. So it may be wise to learn some and do your server-side with node.js instead

Answer (score 1):

- 1) Graphics, basic database functions & database structure
- 2) javascript, jquery, CSS, HTML
- 3) PHP, shell, crontab
- 4) It depends what do you mean by "Game engine"

You can see simple example here http://riseofkings.net/

Explain for framework:

Framework is couple of methods & classes you work with and framework helps you to proccess code more faster.

```
class db
{
    function db(){
         mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "pass");
         mysql_select_db("game");
         $result = query("SELECT user,important,data FROM users WHERE ....");
         $this->user_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }


    function query($query){
         $result = mysql_query($query);
         if ($result) { return $result; }
    }
}
$db = new db();
```

and you can use it like

```
if ($db->user_data['user'] == 1)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: downvoted. I don't think PHP is a front-end language. There's no browser support for PHP right?

Comment: I meant like a 3D game engine?

Comment: @bertzzie: I meant you can do frontend with PHP ... @Ash: 3D in browser?

Comment: no not 3d in browser i meant like we have 3d game engines for 3d games do i need to have a 2d game engine for a browser game?

Comment: as I said, database functions, functions where you select something from DB, etc

Comment: so i can develop a complete browser game by using JS or AS 3.0 with HTML as front-end and PHP or others with MySQL for back-end and Database functions,nothing else required?

Comment: @genesis: Care to elaborate? I'm really not sure how you can do frontend with PHP. Thanks before

Comment: @bertzzie:You can't show frontend output from form by using HTML, you have to use PHP

Comment: @Ash: that's right. You only need JS or AS for front-end, and PHP or others for back-end. But it's going to be so much harder than using C++ for example.

Comment: @Ash: I see. I've removed my downvote :D EDIT: can't remove it unless somebody edits your post. Sorry.

Comment: you definitelly need to make/use framework to make  it easier

Comment: @bertzzie: so you mean if i use C++ it will be easier?

Comment: @genesis: I mean this answer. I've downvoted it, and I can't remove it now. I think I'll just try to upvote it :D

Comment: @genesis: pardon me but what is a framework please elaborate?

Comment: @Ash: sorry if i don't make myself clear. I mean C++ for making a desktop game. Browser game is harder than desktop game. That's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @bertzzie: no problem.I know its harder but its my project so i have to learn it.

Comment: @genesis: "you definitelly need to make/use framework to make it easier" please elaborate this sentence?

Comment: @Ash: answer edited with simple example of framework (it's just part of, but it will help you to get what I mean, you'll have to search throught google) @bertzzie: Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**1. How and where should i start?**
For an online game, I think the most popular development platform for now is Flash. If you want to do the lastest and greatest, then try learning HTML5, with the Canvas API. So you have two choices, maybe you can start by checking which one suits you the most? Read some articles or books maybe?

**2. What should be my front-end programming choices and workflow?**
For Flash, obviously ActionScript. If you want to use HTML5, you will have to go for javascript. JavaScript is supported in all browser. But be careful if you use HTML5, not all of the APIs are supported in all browsers.

**3. What should be my back-end programming choices and workflow?**
For back-end programming, if you want to use your own server for hosting, I'd recommend Python. It's easy to learn and still have some great features. As for the workflow, I don't really understands the question, so would you mind explaining it in comment?

**4. Do i need a game engine for a browser game?**
This I agree with the others: it depends on what do you mean by "Game Engine".

Answer (score 1):

**How and where should i start?**

First is planning. You should decide what your game would be like, and stick to the plan.
You also have to decide on several things, like :

- Who re the intended market? How many users?
- How big is the team needed to develop?
- What will be the revenue model? (pay per download or ads)
- What platform (is Flash ok-do you need to run in IOS or HTML5, Java or .net)?
- Do you need cloud or distributed back end?
- Character Design and Gameplay Design?
- How much budget needed to develop this game? Any sponsor?

**What should be my front-end and back-end programming choices and workflow?**

You can always decide by your own, but everything back to the requirement.Esp how many estimated user, is it server client or just a standalone game. My advice is try take a look on successful case studies and learn from there. Don't waste time to do trial and error. One example is Angry Bird case study :
[Chrome Case study:Angry Bird link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7os4DImjK5U) and [Angry Bird case study link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0Lx4-3LPgw)

**Do i need a game engine for a browser game?**

If your definition of Game engine is according to Wikipedia [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine):

*"Game engines provide a suite of visual development tools in addition to reusable software components."*, my answer will be :

- if it's a small game, one level ( or UI ) my answer it's not.
- if it's a big game, multiple level ( or UI ) my answer it's yes. You don't want to code every level in code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank You,i might sound stupid but i wanted to know does games like Farmville require a game engine?the game i am working on right now is like farmville but its not so rich in content,functionality and graphics like in Farmville,but it does have client server architecture,multiplayer support etc. apart from those it will be connected through Facebook.

Comment: I am planning to develop the game in Flash using Action Script and let AS commute with back-end PHP and databases,for other functionality like login control,user authentication and page layout etc. i will use HTML and Java Script.Did i miss anything? That case study helped a lot.Please can you tell me where i can find more case studies for game development like Farmville or Angry Birds etc.?Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Yes it is just a one level(UI) game, no multiple levels or UIs.There is only one Background image which loads when the game starts and remains static throughout the game thats it, but there are few animations which run over that background image which tell users current progress etc.

Comment: You can use Google and type : "FarmVille Case Studies" and yes, it's quite clear that you don't need any game engine. I don't understand why do you still need Javascript if you want to create your game on Flash. If you choose HTML5 and not using Flash, I can understand why you still need Javascript.

Comment: well the core game will be in Flash but i need HTML for laying it out in a browser right? after that there will be user login authentication etc. like whether the user wants to connect from FB or play directly etc also the input i.d and password needs to be encrypted etc and then sent to the server for opening or displaying that users past data.All this cant be done in HTML i believe?

Comment: My concern is on javascript. Not HTML. Why do you still javascript?

Comment: how will i do user authentication before the actual game has loaded, redirection to FB etc.? If you goto Farmville.com or Evony.com the 1st page you will see is login page.If you view the source code of it you will find lot of JS there although both of them are in Flash completely

Comment: oh i see. The javascript that you were talking abt is for the communication with Facebook.